# Guide user through first time using 'callouts' or 'popovers'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to guide the user through my iPhone app on first time use. I'd like to use a 'callout' or 'popover' pointing to what the user can do on each view. E.g. I'd like a callout/popover with text pointing to 'search' button in a UITableviewCell (see image mockup below with yellow box with text). The popover/callout disappears when pressed.

I've considered using this [3rd party popover library](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController) or a [custom callout library](https://github.com/grgcombs/MultiRowCalloutAnnotationView) but I'm not sure if these are the right approaches. Is there a recommended approach?

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to use tooltips. There are atleast two third party libraries.

[Tourtips](https://github.com/jgurnani/tourTip),  [JDTooltips](https://github.com/JoeFryer/JDFTooltips)